# Append to div with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following HTML code. It is a popup with a collapsible listitems inside:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="wavelistPopup" class="ui-content">
    <div id="wavlistContainer" data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="c" data-content-theme="c" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-r" data-expanded-icon="arrow-d" style="margin:0; width:250px;">
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false">
            <h2>Wave1</h2>
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li>Entfernung: </li>
                <li>Von Autor:</li>
                <li>Schwierigkeit:</li>
                <li>Beschreibung:</li>
                <li><a data-rel="dialog">Erfahrungsberichte</a></li>
                <li><a data-rel="dialog">Wissenswertes</a></li>
                <li><a data-rel="dialog">&Auml;hnliche Waves</a></li>
            </ul>
            <button>Sync</button>
            <button>L&ouml;schen</button>
        </div><!-- /collapsible -->

    </div><!-- /collapsible set -->
</div><!-- /popup -->
```

Now I want to add another collapsible to the wavlistcontainer with the following code:. To do that, I first make a ajax call and work in the callback function.

```
function populateWaveList(){
    console.log("populateWaveList");
    requestWavesInArea(position.position.coords.latitude, position.position.coords.longitude,  
            position.position.coords.latitude+5, position.position.coords.longitude+5, 10, 
            function(waves){ //after AJAX call
            console.log(waves);
                for(var wavei in waves){ // for every element to add
                    var content = "";
                    var wave = waves[wavei];
                    console.log(wave);
                    var content =+ jQuery('somestring';     '<div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false">'+
                                '<h2>'+wave.name+'</h2>'+
                                '<ul data-role="listView">'+    
                                        '<li>Entfernung von Autor: '+'...'+'</li>'+
                                        '<li>Autor: '+wave.creatorname+'</li>'+
                                        '<li>Beschreibung: '+wave.description+'</li>'+
                                        '<li>Umfang: '+'...'+'</li>'+
                                        '<li>Terrain: '+wave.terrainType+'</li>'+
                                        '<li>Autor: '+wave.creatorname+'</li>'+
                                        '<li>Schwierigkeit: '+wave.difficulty+'</li>'+
                                        '<li>ID: '+wave.waveId+'</li>'+
                                        '<li>Datum: '+wave.created+'</li>'+
                                    '</ul>'+
                                    '<button disabled="disabled">Sync</button>'+
                                    '<button disabled="disabled">L&ouml;schen</button>'+
                                '</div>');
                    console.log(content); // returns 'false'
                    $('#wavelistContainer').append(content);
                }
                $('#wavelistPopup').popup('open', { x : 460, y : 180 });
    });
}
```

When I print the content, i get `false` which greately confuses me. Can anyone help me with this please?

Thank you

Comment: If you change the question using the answers, they get irrelevant... This is not how you should use SO...

Comment: you are right, I implemented the mistakes again :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems :

- you're using `=+` instead of `+=`
- you convert to soon the html to a jquery object

This line :

```
​var content =+ 'somestring';
```

is the same as

```
​var content = 0 + 'somestring';
```

and so produces `NaN`.

Instead of

```
content =+  jQuery('<div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false">'+
```

do

```
content +=  '<div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false">'+
```

Note that you should also, for better performances, build only one `content` string and add it only once (declare it before the loop, and append it after the loop).

Comment: I don't think you can get false if you build it with `var content = ""; content += 'somestring';`. Check the code you run.

Comment: I edited my code accordingly. Now I have the problem that the created elements are not collapsible. they are displayed directly.

Comment: You don't even show the code responsible of the collapse... How could I fix it ?

Comment: what do you mean. I tried to recreate the code above dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You have problem your code

```
    content =+  jQuery('<div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false">'+
--------------^-----^
                                    '<h2>'+wave.name+'</h2>'+
                                    '<ul data-role="listView"'>+    
--------------------------------------------------------------^
```

should be

```
content +='<div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false">'+
                                    '<h2>'+wave.name+'</h2>'+
                                    '<ul data-role="listView">'+
```

Comment: I edited my code accordingly. Now I have the problem that the created elements are not collapsible. they are displayed directly.

Comment: @MJB the code looks fine...Hard to figure out what's the problem..Check that all div are closing properly..?

Comment: there is only one div, the div that closes the collapsible, and it's closed.

Comment: @MJB i have no idea about that